# custom pipe not found when refreshing the page

Tags: angular

I have a custom pipe in my application that in order to get it to work I have to remove the pipe, refresh the page, re-add the pipe and save the page.

When the browser picks up the change the pipe works as long as I don't hit refresh. If I do, then I have to go through the process of removing the pipe, getting the page to show in the browser, adding the pipe and saving my changes.

I have the pipe in my declarations of my app.module.client.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { sharedConfig } from './app.module.shared';
import { phonemask } from './components/phone';


@NgModule({
bootstrap: sharedConfig.bootstrap,
declarations: [sharedConfig.declarations, phonemask ],
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    ...sharedConfig.imports
],
exports: [phonemask],
providers: [
    { provide: 'ORIGIN_URL', useValue: location.origin }, 
    [phonemask]
]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Why would I be seeing the on/off behavior from my pipe?

my @angular references are all(4.1.2)

Comment: make use 0f impure pipes

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio or VS Code? Do you have the browser set to not cache the files (Disable cache checked)?

Comment: I'm using visual studio 2017,

Comment: I updated the pipe so it's impure with no change in the behavior. Also, if I copy the URL when the page is working to a different browser to avoid a cache issue the pipe doesn't work in the new browser.

Comment: Well, this is definitely not common behavior. I know of quite a few devs that have had problems with Visual Studio not recognizing changes to pipes. Are you using Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Visual Studio enterprise 2017.

Comment: In most cases I've run into, the devs were able to exit Visual Studio, stop all web server/services, and restart. Then their pipes were recognized and they did not have further problems. I've not heard of anyone else needing to actually remove/re-add it to their project every time.

Comment: Restarting Visual Studio doesn't help, only removing the pipe, bringing up the page, and readding the pipe works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this was due to an ordering issue. make sure you declare your custom pipes before you declare the component that uses them. Also for good measure, I imported the custom pipe before I imported the component that needed it.